# Can I connect my Macbook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2016) to my Macbook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)?

Tags: macbook-pro

A the title suggests, I'd like to connect my macbooks together to easily transfer files and mirror displays when i need to.

Comment: That is two things, Ask Different works better with one question in any post. Transferring files is built-in, just check the right boxes in System Preferences > Sharing.

Answer (score 2):

As long as both Macs are in the same network this can be easily done.

To set it up do the following on both Macs

- Open System Preferences -> Sharing
- Enable Screen Sharing and File Sharing

Afterwards the remote Mac should get listed in any Finder window in the side bar (in the Network part). Click on it and either attach the drive or start screensharing.